# Change background-image to data URI without jQuery

Tags: javascript, background-image, data-uri

I have data uri encoded background-image that works in CSS:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='95' height='6' viewBox='0 0 95 6'%3E%3Ctitle%3Escale mod%3C/title%3E%3Cg id='Layer_2' data-name='Layer 2'%3E%3Cg id='buttonbase'%3E%3Cg id='scale_mod' data-name='scale mod'%3E%3Cpath d='M95,6H0V5H95Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M94.953,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M86.4,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M77.853,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M69.3,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M60.753,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M52.2,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M43.653,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M35.1,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M26.553,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M18,5h-.9V3H18Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M9.452,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M.9,5H0V3H.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M89.11,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M80.56,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M72.01,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M63.46,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M54.91,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M46.36,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M37.81,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M29.26,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M20.71,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M12.16,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M3.61,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

Is there is a way to assign it dynamically using querySelector?

```
document.querySelector('.element').style.backgroundImage= ...
```

Comment: isn't you just  showing the answer?

Comment: I don't think the url is in base64 anyway.

Comment: It could be, but I've lost in quotes.

Comment: OK, I think I get it, answer posted.

Comment: the url still not [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), I'm going to remove relevant text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to overcome the quotes problem.

```js
document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundImage = `url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='95' height='6' viewBox='0 0 95 6'%3E%3Ctitle%3Escale mod%3C/title%3E%3Cg id='Layer_2' data-name='Layer 2'%3E%3Cg id='buttonbase'%3E%3Cg id='scale_mod' data-name='scale mod'%3E%3Cpath d='M95,6H0V5H95Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M94.953,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M86.4,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M77.853,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M69.3,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M60.753,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M52.2,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M43.653,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M35.1,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M26.553,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M18,5h-.9V3H18Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M9.452,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M.9,5H0V3H.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M89.11,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M80.56,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M72.01,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M63.46,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M54.91,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M46.36,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M37.81,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M29.26,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M20.71,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M12.16,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M3.61,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E")`
```

```css
div{width:100px;height:100px;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

also you can escape the quotes. (I just replace `"` with `\"` )

```js
document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundImage = "url(\"data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='95' height='6' viewBox='0 0 95 6'%3E%3Ctitle%3Escale mod%3C/title%3E%3Cg id='Layer_2' data-name='Layer 2'%3E%3Cg id='buttonbase'%3E%3Cg id='scale_mod' data-name='scale mod'%3E%3Cpath d='M95,6H0V5H95Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M94.953,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M86.4,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M77.853,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M69.3,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M60.753,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M52.2,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M43.653,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M35.1,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M26.553,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M18,5h-.9V3H18Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M9.452,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M.9,5H0V3H.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M89.11,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M80.56,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M72.01,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M63.46,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M54.91,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M46.36,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M37.81,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M29.26,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M20.71,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M12.16,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M3.61,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E\")"
```

```css
div{width:100px;height:100px;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: " template literal" works, however "Dreamweaver" throws an error - Parsing error:Unexpected character "`". Should I safely ignore it?

Comment: @Serg yes I think you can safely ignore it. (if you want to more backward compatible, use escaped quote `\'` and `\"` would also work)

Comment: @Serg another example added.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to convert your base64 image into a css class and assign with document.getElement and add css class.

```js
function setImage() {
  element = document.getElementById('app')
  element.className += " image";

}
```

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='95' height='6' viewBox='0 0 95 6'%3E%3Ctitle%3Escale mod%3C/title%3E%3Cg id='Layer_2' data-name='Layer 2'%3E%3Cg id='buttonbase'%3E%3Cg id='scale_mod' data-name='scale mod'%3E%3Cpath d='M95,6H0V5H95Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M94.953,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M86.4,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M77.853,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M69.3,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M60.753,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M52.2,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M43.653,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M35.1,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M26.553,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M18,5h-.9V3H18Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M9.452,5h-.9V3h.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M.9,5H0V3H.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M89.11,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M80.56,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M72.01,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M63.46,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M54.91,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M46.36,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M37.81,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M29.26,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M20.71,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M12.16,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3Cpath d='M3.61,0h.9V5h-.9Z' style='fill:%23c8c8c8'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="setImage()">set image</button>
  <div id="app">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you use an identifier to get a specific element to assign the background image to, if you want to use a class get the list of elements with that class - check if you have at lease one element, take that element and assign the background image via Javascript - Also just noticed your base64 doesn't appear to be properly encoded Base64 data:

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName("element"); // or $(".element")
var myBase64Content = "data:image/svg+xml,..."; //Insert base 64 encoding here

// We have at least one element, take first and assign background image
if(myElements.length > 0) {
     myElements[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + myBase64Content + "')";
}
```